# Windows resized after sleep with external display connected to Macbook Pro via DP to usb-c

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport, resolution

I have an external display ASUS VG279 connected to my MBP 2018 via Display Port to USB-C cable by moshi (sold on Apple's website). I use 1080p resolution for the display and my macOS version is Catalina (10.15.4). When my laptop wakes up after sleep, all my windows resized (smaller than should be) and I have to manually adjust it every time. My laptop is always on a charge.

How can I do so the size of windows kept to the external display resolution after sleep?

The issue doesn't happen if I lock my computer manually and then unlock it, only if it was put to sleep according to the schedule in energy saver preferences.

UPD: I don't know what happened but now after the laptop wakes up I see my windows minimized and a small part of them picking out from the right side of the screen, it's like I have a two display setup and the windows were on the right screen even though my laptop lid is always closed.

Comment: What if you power cycle the monitor?  Does that fix the issue?

Comment: @Allan I don't know what is that, how can I do that?

Comment: Turn it off, then turn it back on. Wait a second or two before you turn it on

Comment: @Allan if I do that, windows keep the correct size

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying.  Did you try power cycling the monitor?

Comment: @Allan did you mean if I reset my monitor by powering off/on, does that fix my issue with the next sleep/awake? No, it doesn't. What I've also noticed is that if I lock my screen manually and unlock it windows sizes are ok but if the laptop goes to sleep automatically according to the energy saver settings and then I wake it up then the issue appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing and using Display Maid